# How to automate filtering in RadComboBox

Tags: c#, testing, telerik, radcombobox

Telerik RadComboBox has an Input Area control, which displays the selected item. Depending on the RadComboBox properties, the user can use this area to type in a new value and hence enables filtering. I need to automate entering a value in input area and verify that the item is returned/highlighted. [image]

I'm able to enter the item programmatically in input area. But I'm unable to verify if the data I entered exists in the combobox as there is no any property to differentiate if an item is highlighted or not.. Here is what I tried so far. Could someone help?

```
var comboBox = broker.Find<RadComboBox>(Reference);
var inputArea= comboBox.Find.ByAutomationId<TextBox>("PART_EditableTextBox");
if (!comboBox.IsDropDownOpen)
  {                
    comboBox.DropDownPopup.User.Click();
    inputArea.SetText(true,ComboBoxItem, 10, 10, true);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find here a demo and the code behind. 
[telerik autocomplete demo RTFM](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/functionality/autocompleteclientside/defaultcs.aspx)

If any help is needed to apply this solution ask in comment i will edit the answer.

regards, 
Pierre.